# Aggregation tool in BIRT : display a count like number on a table column

Tags: count, birt

It must be very easy, baut i can't display a very simple filtered agregation on a table header row in BIRT 3.7. I manage to use count aggregation on groups headers or footers, buet not a filtered aggregation on a simple column table.

USE case : my sql statement car return the string value "ERROR..." for a string field name TEST. The query returns 734 results. My table display all the results.
In the header row i just want to diplay a count of which would be in SQL a count like "ERROR%".

I can't manage to do that whit the aggregation tool !
[aggregation builder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VK3gp.png)

Many thanks for your help.

Julien

Answer (score 0):

as i can't manage to find the correct way of filtering my aggregation, i provide the results from my SQL request. By i'd be glad to find the dynamic way of filtering it.
Here is an image of a column that contains strings with "ERR". Le top field in red is my aggregation field served by a slq like '%ERR :%' statement.
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kSsMu.png)